# Tub stem adapter for handle

Tags: plumbing, shower, bathtub, valve

Does there exist any way of adapting one type of valve stem to another handle that won't fit it? I have a gerber two handle (separate hot/cold) system, and my wife bought some handles that geometrically won't work with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not seen an adapter that will allow different handles to be used than the original design. If the holes in the handles are too large, you could fill them with epoxy,let it start to harden and them press the handles in place over the stems. If the holes are too small, then you might be able to file the stems down a bit. None of the above ideas are really good because those handles will take a lot of wear over the years and if they don't fit as designed, they'll eventually come loose and you'll have to modify them again. If you have to do maintenance, you'll need to remove the handles. Best bet would be to return the handles and get the proper fitting ones. You should be able to take one of the old handles and get an accurate match from your home store or a plumbing supply store.

Comment: There are "universal" handles, which I've used on my system before. They worked just as well as the official handles. I wish there were just an adapter that could do both sides (the stem and handle).

Comment: I did cut one of the stems, and it was a pretty good fit. It doesn't look like it will wear down for a good long while, so this may be a solution if there's no adapter on the market.

Comment: @user3337629   The universal handles have larger holes to accommodate the adapter.  those adapters wouldn't fit in the smaller holes of custom handles...  If cutting the stem works, have at it. You should be good with a metal to metal contact.